# How to Load AutoLisp file From VB.net

Tags: vb.net, autolisp

Is that possible to load a **Lisp** file from **VB.NET**? I am currently using **Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express**. I tried one like this below.

```
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime
Imports Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop

Public Class CLass1
    Public Sub LoadLisp()
        Dim app As AcadApplication = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.AcadApplication
        Dim command As String = "(load ""F:/HVAC Tools/My Duct/combine_to_acad.vlx"")"
        app.SendCommand(command)
    End Sub
End Class
```

But It doesn't work.Please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with ARX, not VB.Net, so maybe there are some differences, but generaly You may use LISP expresion as command. for example like this:

```
Dim app As AcadApplication = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.AcadApplication         
Dim command As String = "(load ""C:/path/file.lsp"")"
app.ActiveDocument.SendCommand(command)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am not strong in VB.NET.

Comment: So what do You expect? You have sample code to load LISP file by VB.net . that's not what You asked for?

Comment: Sorry, that comment was wrong sent. Actually, I didn't mean to send. I just typed it ,and wrong click "Enter". I forgot to delete it. Sorry bro.

Comment: I tried the similar one to the above one that you sampled. But I used `<CommandMethod("MyLisp")> _`.  And, I want to modify it to load at **Startup** without using **Command**.

Comment: So You may load lisp at startup without VB.Net. check here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638593/what-is-the-order-of-load-autocad-plugins