# How to open a DWG and directly send a command to AutoCADLT?

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin

I have to open a dwg and then execute an AutoCADLT command, immediately after the program load the file.
I know that there is a switch to open a "script", but since the LT version of the program can't handle scripts, I'm wondering if there is a similar switch for commands.

To open my file I'm using this string:

`"path-of-the-program\program.exe" path-of-the-dwg\file.dwg <CAD COMMAND>`

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The only method that I am aware of to facilitate the execution a command or set of commands on drawing startup **without** the use of an API (such as the AutoLISP API) is to use the `acad.exe` command line switch `/b` to open AutoCAD and run the Script file whose filename follows the `/b` switch.

I describe this briefly as part of my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48644196/7531598), and there is also [this off-site resource](https://www.afralisp.net/archive/lisp/Switches.htm) describing the various command-line switches available, which I will also summarise below:

> ### Switch Syntax and Examples
>
> - #### /b
>
>   Open a drawing and runs a Script. Drawing name is optional.
>
>   ```
>   path ["drawing file"] /b "script"
>   "C:\AutoCAD 2002\acad.exe" /b "C:\scripts\MyScript"
>   ```
> - #### /c
>
>   Specifies the hardware configuration file to use.
>
>   ```
>   path /c "Configuration File"
>   "C:\AutoCAD 2002\acad.exe" /c "C:\myconfigs\MyConfig"
>   ```
> - #### /nologo
>
>   Starts AutoCAD without the splash screen.
>
>   ```
>   path  /nologo
>   "C:\AutoCAD 2002\acad.exe" /nologo
>   ```
> - #### /p
>
>   Starts AutoCAD with the specified Profile name. If the Profile does not exist, AutoCAD uses the current Profile.
>
>   ```
>   path  /b profile
>   "C:\AutoCAD 2002\acad.exe" /p "C:\profiles\MyProfile"
>   ```
> - #### /r
>
>   Resets all AutoCAD default settings, printers and system pointing device.
>
>   ```
>   path /r
>   "C:\AutoCAD 2002\acad.exe" /r
>   ```
> - #### /s
>
>   Designates additional Support Paths.
>
>   ```
>   path /s "Support Paths"
>   "C:\AutoCAD 2002\acad.exe" /s "C:\Blocks;C:\Lisp;C:\VBA"
>   ```
> - #### /t
>
>   Creates a new drawing based on a Template or Prototype drawing. Drawing name
>     is optional.
>
>   ```
>   path  ["drawing file"] /t "Template File"
>   "C:\AutoCAD 2002\acad.exe" /t "C:\MyTemplates\MyTemplate"
>   ```
> - #### /v
>
>   Opens a drawing with a predefined view.
>
>   ```
>   path  ["drawing file"] /v "View Name"
>   "C:\AutoCAD 2002\acad.exe" "MyDrawing" /v "MyView"
>   ```

You may also wish to refer to the [official Autodesk documentation](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2019/ENU/AutoCAD-LT/files/GUID-8675B657-8C15-4594-BDFB-644B66BD02D7-htm.html).

Whilst AutoCAD LT does support the use of Script files (`.scr`), such Script files will only be able to invoke native AutoCAD commands with no access to any AutoCAD API.